# "DefaultKeyBinding" Hex code for ML's "⌘ ⌘" Start Dictation command?

Tags: macos, voice-dictation, keyboard

I have a set customized keyboard bindings located in a `plist` file at `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.Dict` which works with Hex keys like..

`"\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfLine:"; /* Home */`

or for "Non-Printable Key Codes", like so..

Backtab ( <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>)   `\U0019`

I'd like to add a new keyboard shortcut for the start dictation commands in Mountain lion, aka, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd>.

Is there such a code?  Or is NSresponder making them up on the fly, other private magic, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the actions of double-presses of modifier keys is probably impossible. There isn't even a code point for the fn key in [CORPCHAR.TXT](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/APPLE/CORPCHAR.TXT).

But if you're looking to add a different shortcut for toggling speech, you should be looking for method names instead of shortcut strings.

I tried [using strings to find method names for starting dictation](https://superuser.com/questions/455755/how-to-explore-more-defaults-write-tweaks-on-os-x). `startDictation:` and `startSpeechCaptureForDictation:` seemed promising, but neither worked in `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`.

Even if you were able to change the shortcut in `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`, it wouldn't work in applications that don't support the customizable keybindings.

What's wrong with just changing it in System Preferences?

[image]

If you want to use a shortcut that isn't allowed, you might be able to change `CustomizedDictationHotKey` in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.speech.recognition.AppleSpeechRecognition.prefs.plist`.